# How to reference JSON attributes with a period in their name from underscore.js javascript template library

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using underscore template engine (as part of Backbone.js) and have an issue where an attribute of the JSON object has a period in it i.e.

```
{
"id": 1234,
"company.id": 4321
}
```

When I try to access this in the underscore template I get a JavaScript error:

```
Company ID: <@= company.id @>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible and how it's done to access attributes with period in them. I'm not in a position to change the generation of the JSON.

cowper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way around that is to wrap another object around it so that you can use `[]` to access `'company.id'`. For example, your template could look like this:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/html">
    id: <%= o.id %><br>
    company: <%= o['company.id'] %>
</script>​
```

and your JavaScript like this:

```
var html = _.template($('#tmpl').html(), {
    o: {
        "id": 1234,
        "company.id": 4321
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wtLkP/1/
​
The Underscore template compiler uses `with` to supply the context for simple things like `<%= x %>` in the templates so I don't think you're going to be able to do any better than the `o.` trick above. Underscore builds a function from your template, you can see the function's source by looking at the `source` attribute of the function:

```
var t = _.template(template_source);
console.log(t.source);
```

That will give you something like this:

```
function(obj){
var __p='';var print=function(){__p+=Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '')};
with(obj||{}){
__p+='\n    id: '+
( o.id )+
'<br>company: '+
( o['company.id'] )+
' and stuff\n';
}
return __p;
}
```

and you can see why just `<%= [x] %>` won't work: [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) only adjusts the current scope, it can't make `[x]` into valid JavaScript.

Comment: Looks good thx. I read about the use of `with` somewhere but I didn't grasp what it was and still don't. I did see that it was possible to set the name of variable in use by passing `{variable: 'data'}` or something like that. I got the impression that doing that meant I could access the attribute using `data["company.id"]` but couldn't get that working also. Thanks for the answer.